# How to connect Candidate(FLS) button to specific account record type?

Tags: visualforce, account, record-type, lightning-quickaction, field-service-lightning

In my org we have a few account record types. The button Candidates(positioned as action on account layout) works perfectly for just one record type and I want it to work with other ones too(I am getting error when I click get candidate button "this is not *name of the record type that works"). How can I change this? I suppose that someone before me who installed this package changed something and put rule that candidate should work only with specific record type. Does anyone know where this configuration is made as I searched everywhere and couldn't find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, there was a lookup field with filter for just one record type ,otherwise it returns error, on work order object and that was a problem, If anyone struggles with this just ad OR with a filter for second record type that you need.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thanks for coming back to add the answer, as that could help future readers.